# Upgrading to Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

having some issues trying to upgrade to Laravel 5.2 from the previous latest version.

On composer update or any artisan class I get the follow error ...

Class validator does not exist

Can not work out whats going on at all.

Any ideas?

Many thanks!

Comment: Which version are you trying to upgrade from? Are you following all the steps of [Laravel 5.2 docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0)?

Comment: From 5.1.11. Yeah followed all steps and gone over multiple times to make sure I have not missed anything.

Comment: When I try to  use existing form request validation, and submit an empty form (so to validate it) it throws the following exception ... HttpResponseException. This was replaced with Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidationException right?

Comment: I've just finished upgrading in my project and took several hours, It depends on the size of your project, and you need to be methodical to tackle the issues one by one. Can you post the code that generates the error and the output (the whole error with the stack trace) in a pastebin?

Comment: Also, maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34636445/formrequest-failed-validation-returns-500-error-instead-of-422-with-errors-afte#comment57018102_34636445) helps on this, specially [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34636445/formrequest-failed-validation-returns-500-error-instead-of-422-with-errors-afte#comment57018102_34636445)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out Whoops was catching a HttpResponseException of which the upgrade docs do say could cause issues. So removed Whoops as problem solved.